# Navbar is not visible in some parts of my page

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to create a webpage which has a sticky Navbar and Parallax Effect. It has 2 sections: first is the picture and under is some text. The navbar is only visible in the text sections.

Unfortunately, the navbar is, like, getting under the picture and then pops out when I scroll down to the text section. Would be grateful if someone could help me with this problem (first time making a webpage)!

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  /* padding: 0px 30px;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.name {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  padding-right: 150px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  transition: .4s;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="name">
        <img src="logoimg.png> </img>
       </div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=" # " class="sec1 "> Home</a> </li>
          <li><a href="# " class="sec2 "> Who we are</a> </li>
          <li><a href="# " class="sec3 "> What we do</a> </li>
          <li><a href="# " class="sec4 "> Our projects</a> </li>
          <li><a href="# " class="sec5 "> Contact us</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are going for here. FIrst you are missing a closing </div> for your "container" class div. Is the <nav> supposed to be encompassing the entire body of the header or just the <ul>?

Comment: @JJWillMC thank you, I’ll add the closing tag, nav is for the entire header

Comment: I believe you need some javascript in order to achieve the "sticky" part of the navbar.  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp     Also, here is a great tutorial for your "parallax" part    https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

Comment: 1. you are missing closing double quotation in the image tag and you don't need to add `</img>`   2. you are missing closing `</div>` tag before closing the `nav`. fix these first

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index` to the CSS for nav:

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    top: 0;
    padding:15px 0px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 20
}
```

Comment: @Naira try a higher z-index number